# Property not found on object of type (category not visible)

Tags: objective-c, implementation

**SOLVED: It turns out I was importing the wrong header file that contains the category.**

I get this error: `Property 'xx_store' not found on object of type 'XXFeedback *'`

Yet `XXFeedback` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to which I've added a category that adds the `xx_store` method.

I've made sure the category's implementation fie is included in my target's Compile Sources build phase.

I also tried adding these "Other Linker Flags" settings in my target's Build Settings: `-ObjC` and `-all_load`, as per [Building Objective-C static libraries with categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

I also did a project clean and rebuild.

**The code**

In `XXFoundation/FileA.h`:

```
@interface NSManagedObject (MyCategory)
@property (readonly, nonatomic) XXStore *xx_store;
@end
```

In `XXFoundation/FileA.m`:

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (MyCategory)

- (XXStore *)xx_store
{
  ...
}
```

In FileB.m:

```
#import <XXFoundation/FileA.h>

...
XXStore *store = _feedback.xx_store;
...
```

Comment: Does the .h for XXFeedback #include NSManagedObject+MyCategory?  I don't see your declaration for XXFeedback.

Comment: `XXFeedback` doesn't need to because it's a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, and the category on `NSManagedObject` is included in the file in which I use the instance of `XXFeedback`.

Comment: There needs to be a #import of the category declaration somewhere in FileB.m in order for the compiler to know about the method when compiling FileB.m.  That #import could be in FileB.m, or something it imports or something its imports imports, etc.

Comment: In FileB.m you have an import of FileA.h, is that a typo?  Shouldn't it be importing FileB.h?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are working on some static library. If so there is an issue when linking against an Objective-C static library that contains categories. Check out this technical Q&A for more info: [Building Objective-C static libraries with categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was importing the wrong header file that contained the category.